# Get ALL instances of ONE attribute instead of just one

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am displaying graphs based on selection of checkboxes and have run into a small problem.

I am currently looping through and selecting only the first graph, even when a select-all checkbox is checked - meaning I get however many amounts of the same first graph instead of the ten unique graphs.

As you will see in the code below, the previous line I was using that is commented out:

```
//var fnInstance=$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].attributes[1].value;
```

Works perfectly in Firefox **ONLY** - it displays all graphs correct etc. but does not work in Chrome/IE due to the way it is attempting to access elements.

I have replaced it with these two lines:

```
$el = $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview).first();
var fnInstance = $el.find("input").attr("onclick");
```

The two lines I have replaced it with cause everything to function in all three browsers (no errors in IE or Chrome anymore), **however** the only graph that is ever shown is the first one found - if three elements have been selected then 3 versions of the first graph will show instead of the 3 unique ones.

**The full code is below, and console.logs of what the elements contain are below that:**

```
for (var i=0;i<$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children.length;i++)
{

 if (!$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].checked)
 {  
        $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].checked=true;


//var fnInstance=$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].attributes[1].value;

        $el = $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview).first();
        var fnInstance = $el.find("input").attr("onclick");


        fnInstance=fnInstance.substr(15).substr(0,fnInstance.length-2);

        var flagsInstance=fnInstance.split(new RegExp(","));

        var graph = {
                id: seqId,
                entityName: flags[6].substr(1).substr(0, flags[6].length - 2),
                entity: flags[5].substr(1).substr(0, flags[5].length - 2),
                idCounter: flags[4],
                counterName: flags[3].substr(1).substr(0, flags[3].length - 2),
                ivmanager: flags[7].substr(1).substr(0, flags[7].length - 2),
                chart: null,
                pointsToShowX: null,
                borneInf: null,
                unite: "",
                idInstance: flagsInstance[2].substr(1).substr(0, flagsInstance[2].length - 2),
                instanceName: flagsInstance[3].substr(1).substr(0, flagsInstance[3].length - 2),
                listPdsNull: new Array(),
                countInstance: idTreeview + "_" + i,
                countGraph: -1
            };

        seqId++;        
        graphs[graphsLastId]=graph;     
        graphsLastId++;
    }
}
```

**Console.logs of elements:**

[image]

Any help would be greatly appeciated as I have spent hours trying to work out (another previous employee's) code..

I basically just need a browser-friendly version of this line -

```
 var fnInstance=$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].attributes[1].value;
```

Comment: You still seem to mix jQuery and plain DOM methods.

Comment: @Bergi It's not my code, I'm as confused about why it was done like this as you are.. I would go and change everything to JQuery but right now this is the only 'bug' I have left and deadline's calling.. just don't have a clue how I can replicate the commented-out line in a way that IE and Chrome accept..

Comment: For starts, you could shorten your checkbox selector using `$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview + ' input[type="checkbox"]:checked')`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect - how should `$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview).first().find("input").attr("onclick");` select different elements? What should it do instead? And the DOM structure on which your code operates would help a lot

Comment: I thought the problem was more the .first() part - as I assumed that if this was changed it would find all child elements with input and activate their onClick methods, but I cannot find a method to use that will replicate a browser-friendly version of the commented out line.

Comment: The line should find all inputs and update their on-click methods accordingly instead of just the first one found. Currently, these two lines select all checkboxes but update them with the first graph found, whereas before all unique graphs were shown but only in Firefox.

Comment: It does find all of them - the `first` is for your id selector which should return only one element anyway. Yet, the [`attr` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) will only return the value for the first element - what did you expect? And wtf do you mean by "*activate their onClick methods*"?

Comment: Are you attempting to trigger the `onclick` event (simulate a click)? Then you're looking for the `trigger` method.

`$el = $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview).first().find("input").trigger("click");`

Comment: I expected the exact same outcome as $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].attributes[1].value; but I didn't get it or the graphs would be displaying properly. I meant as in grab the value of the onclick of each input involved.

Comment: You mean grab the function registered to `onclick`?

Comment: Yes Jan the function registered to it. Literally a compatible version of what my line that's commented is doing except that only works in Firefox as accessing by order isn't a great idea. The trigger line you just put only selects one whereas I need it to select all instances

Comment: How about `inputfns = $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview).first().find("input")["click"];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original:

```
fnInstance=$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].attributes1.value;
```

My suggestion:

```
var changedIforPsedoSelctor = i+1;
var nthChild = ":nth-child("+changedIforPsedoSelctor+")";
var fnInstance = $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview).children(nthChild).children(":first-child").attr("onclick");
```

I believe that should do it, however it would be much easier to answer your questions if you provided the HTML markup for this particular problem. I am also assuming that attributes[1] is equal to "onclick" in the selector.

Comment: Yes, if you look at my console.logs it shows what each part of the statement means, so yes it is the on-click selector. This code you put however returns me with an error "fnInstance is not defined"

Comment: Thats probably because I forgot to put a var infront of fnInstance, have edited now :)

Comment: I already added the var but still undefined :/ It seems to make it 'undefined' as fnInstance = undefined in a console log below it.

Comment: When I console-log your three lines I get this - changedIforPsedoSelctor =1
nthChild =:nth-child(1)
fnInstance =undefined. Judging by this I'm guessing it's the fnInstance line that's not compiling

Comment: Try changing .first() to .children(":first-child")

Comment: Great that I was able to help :)

Comment: It will let me award you the bounty in 18 hours btw so you should get it tommorow